# Comparing two sets in python

Tags: python, set

Why do I get the results shown?

```
>>> x = {"a","b","1","2","3"}  
>>> y = {"c","d","f","2","3","4"}  
>>> z=x<y        
>>> print(z)
False
>>> z=x>y
>>> print(z)
False
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `<` and `>` operators are testing for strict [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset). Neither of those sets is a subset of the other.

```
{1, 2} < {1, 2, 3}  # True
{1, 2} < {1, 3}  # False
{1, 2} < {1, 2}  # False -- not a *strict* subset
{1, 2} <= {1, 2}  # True -- is a subset
```

Comment: And thus if a and b are sets, you cannot replace `if not a <= b` by `if a > b`, although flake8 might ask you to.

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the python documentation --

> In addition, both Set and ImmutableSet support set to set comparisons.
>   Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is
>   contained in the other (each is a subset of the other). A set is less
>   than another set if and only if the first set is a proper subset of
>   the second set (is a subset, but is not equal). A set is greater than
>   another set if and only if the first set is a proper superset of the
>   second set (is a superset, but is not equal).

Answer (score 2):

When working with sets, > and < are relational operators.
hence, these operations are used to see if one set is the **proper subset** of the other, which is False for as neither is the proper subset of the other.